# GWT Drop Down Menu with images

Tags: image, gwt

I want to make a drop down menu with images. This means:

```
 ImageListName
  image.png
  image1.png
  ......
  imageN.png
```

There should be only images no text and I want to select on image like when you can choose an avatar. 
I'm not sure which approach is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MenuBar HomeMenu = new MenuBar();
final String image = "<img src='"+GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/images/down-arrow.png' height='25px' width='25px'/>";
        SafeHtml addActivityImagePath = new SafeHtml() {
            @Override
            public String asString() {
                return image;
            }
        };
HomeMenu.addItem(new MenuItem(addActivityImagePath,mainMenu));
```

Take a look at the Combobox or Suggestion box in [Advanced GWT Components.](http://advanced-gwt.sourceforge.net/text-and-button.html)

You won't be able to do this with a ListBox, because it just creates an HTML < select> element. You can use a [MenuBar](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html) that has one menu with [MenuItems](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuItem.html) in it to simulate a dropdown with complex widgets inside it. You will also be able to style the dropdown rather than rely on browser-styled form elements.use MenuBar instead of ListBox and place any widget you want inside the MenuItem to simulate a ListBox. Regular ListBoxes will only allow you to specify plain text.