# Icon inside a DropDownButton

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap

is it possible to display an icon inside a DropdownButton (for each element)?
I'm new to gwt-bootsrap and don't know how to do. I use gwt-bootstrap-2.0.4.0.

Comment: For example the DropdownButton from the showcase: http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/2.0.4.0/#component:

Comment: I found the answer! I used NavLink what was the wrong component. It works with NavWidget.

Comment: Please post it as answer !! So that others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! I used NavLink what was the wrong component. It works with NavWidget

```
<b:DropdownButton text="Foo">
<b:NavWidget>
    <g:HorizontalPanel>
        <g:Image resource="{res.fooBarPicture}" />
        <g:HTMLPanel>Bar</g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:HorizontalPanel>
</b:NavWidget>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have Icons/images in the dropdown, I think if found what you need. If you need text I don't know if it will also work. Look here: [GWT Drop Down Menu with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276715/gwt-drop-down-menu-with-images)

If you need also Text you could look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/AddingimagetodropdownSmartGWT.htm). But this is with SmartGwt so you probably won't like it.

Sarajog